# Label Text not updating even when using Refresh, Invalidate, and DoEvents

Tags: vb.net, forms, label

My code is designed to be a control system for a 2-axis motion system. I have 2 drives that each output a count of their steps. I can read the device, update a property, and update the text field of a label. However, it does not update the form. When I use a message box, I can display the text value being correct, but nothing updates the label.

I'm happy to try any suggestions, but I've been fighting this for about 16 hours and I'm at my wits end - as evidenced by the clear overkill/terrible coding that is shown in the code. I can't understand why it's not updating.

Additionally, a manual button with all versions seen below to refresh a form doesn't update the control.

Direction, recommendations?

```
Private Sub PositionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    If TraverseController.InvokeRequired Then
        TraverseController.Invoke(
               New EventHandler(Of EventArgs)(AddressOf PositionChanged), sender, e)
        Return
    End If
    'RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(TraverseController, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Position"))
    MessageBox.Show(TraverseController.lblLinearDrivePosDisp.Text)
    TraverseController.lblLinearDrivePosDisp.Text = CStr(_position)
    Application.DoEvents()
    TraverseController.lblLinearDrivePosDisp.ResetBindings()
    TraverseController.GBDrivePositionDisp.Refresh()
    TraverseController.lblLinearDrivePosDisp.Refresh()
    TraverseController.Refresh()
    TraverseController.Invalidate()
    TraverseController.Update()
    Application.DoEvents()
    MessageBox.Show(TraverseController.lblLinearDrivePosDisp.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any code there that is attempting to update a label.

Comment: I assign the text property to the label in the 8th line (including the empty line), tell the application to do events next, reset the bindings, then refresh the group box and label...Am I completely missing something, @Blackwood?

Comment: Just tried adding a line for both the visible sub above and the button call using Label.Update - no effect.

Comment: As TnTinMn's answer suggests, `TraverseController.lblLinearDrivePosDisp` is probably not a label on the form you are looking it, but rather on the default instance of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: TraverseController is form's class name.

This looks like a VB default form instance issue.  It is apparent that you are trying to properly marshal control interaction back to the UI thread by using checking `TraverseController.InvokeRequired`.  However, due to the way these default instance are created, `TraverseController.InvokeRequired` is creating a new instance of `TraverseController` on the secondary thread and all subsequent code is modifying that instance and not the one created on the UI thread.

One way to deal with this is to pass a synchronizing control instance to the class where `PositionChanged` changed method is defined and check that control's `InvokeRequired` method instead of `TraverseController.InvokeRequired`.  If the containing class is itself a UI control, then use that class instance (`Me.InvokeRequired`).

Comment: *One way to deal with this is to pass a synchronizing control instance to the class where PositionChanged changed method is defined and check that control's InvokeRequired method instead of TraverseController.InvokeRequired.*

I don't quite follow this - I'm sorry for needing clarification on this. Could you note where I might find that in the MSDN or any other explanation site? I succeeded in using a synchronizing object with a timer and while this appears similar, I can't seem to find it in the documentation. Thanks, @TnTinMn.

Comment: @EngiNerd, don't be embarrassed about asking for clarification. In my experience most people don't have a firm grasp on this topic as the documentation is not the greatest and does not use the best terms.  All WinForm controls implement the [ISynchronizeInvoke Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke?view=netframework-4.8) as such, you can use **any** control created on the UI thread as a synchronizing object as long as its Handle is created.

Comment: @EngiNerd, con't:  All I meant was that if the `PositionChanged` method is defined in a non-control class, is that you pass a valid control reference to it to use for checking `InvokeRequired`.  If you can provide more detail on your code layout, I can give you a general example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I'm figuring it out, slowly.